# How to get 7th day from today using Sql Server 2008R2?

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting the 7th day from today of every month with this query:

```
select * 
from dbo.Table 
where day(col_Dob) = day(DATEADD(day, 7, getdate()))
```

I want exactly the 7th day date of births from today of the same month.

Comment: Can you please show sample input and output? Your question is unclear at the moment.

Comment: This is difficult to understand. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when you run the query on the 30th of the month?

Comment: You would also need to join on month `and month(col_dob) = month(dateadd(day,7,getdate()))`.